# object-oriented programming took people -- where did it take them? I don't get it

Tags: comprehension

[James Gosling - Thoughts for Students](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r19P3y1VBiw#t=1m00s) (at the 1 minute mark, the entire video is 1 minute and 26 seconds long):

> And it's pretty easy to explain how object-oriented programming **took** people who've never programmed before because it's kind of like dealing with objects in the world around you. But if people have already learned how to program COBOL, it's kind of strange and in their head they're trying to map COBOL on Java.

I don't know how to understand *took*. What does he really mean by *OOP took people*?

Comment: I think in this context it means 'interested'.

Comment: Compare the figurative use of "captivated" or "grabbed" to mean "interested".   To "take someone" is to take them captive (that's the literal meaning).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same idiomatic usage as...

> [*How does that **take** you?*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22how%20does%20that%20take%20you%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)
>    (How do you feel about that?)

...which is also reflected in...

> [*I'm quite **taken** by it*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22quite%20taken%20by%20it%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)
>    (I'm impressed by it)

So if you like, you could see ***to take*** here as meaning ***to create an impression, to affect***. But as I said, it's an idiomatic usage, and you probably shouldn't risk using it in many contexts yourself.

For example, the (far more colloquial) usage *How does that **grab** you?* reflects the literal sense of *take captive, captivate*, but few native speakers would ever say *I'm quite **grabbed** by it*.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds strange to me --- the kind of thing someone might say when they start speaking with one thought, then change their mind halfway through and end up saying something ungrammatical.

One similar phrase the speaker might have had in mind is "take to", for example,

> People *took to* object-oriented programming because...

This means that people found OOP appealing for whatever reason. But note that in this usage, the people are the subject, and the thing they enjoy is the object, rather than the other way around like in your citation.